# Why I am getting this compilation error?

Tags: c#

Why I cannot use option #1 below. Option 2 works fine

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
             //Option 1  
            //Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApplication2.Program.SomeMethod(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)' has some invalid argument
            //Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
            SomeMethod(new List<string>().Add("This give compilation Error"));

            //Option 2 
            List<string> MyMessages = new List<string>();
            MyMessages.Add("This compiles fine");
            SomeMethod(MyMessages);
        }

        static void SomeMethod(List<string> Messages)
        {
            foreach (string Message in Messages)
                Console.WriteLine(Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {

                //There was a syntax error in your code. It should be declare like this
                SomeMethod(new List<string>(){("This give compilation Error")});

                //Option 2 
                List<string> MyMessages = new List<string>();
                MyMessages.Add("This compiles fine");
                SomeMethod(MyMessages);
            }

            static void SomeMethod(List<string> Messages)
            {
                foreach (string Message in Messages)
                    Console.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Other replies are correct as they point to the stupid thing I was doing, but this is what I really wanted to do. Thanks all

Answer (score 14):

[`List<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) returns `void`. Your code fails in the same way that this would fail:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>().Add("This wouldn't work");
```

However, C# 3 to the rescue with collection initializers:

```
SomeMethod(new List<string> { "Woot!" });
```

Answer (score 5):

Because .Add() return void type instead of List. You can however do this

```
SomeMethod(new List<string>() { "This give compilation Error" });
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because the `List<T>.Add()` method doesn't return the element that you just added to the list. It returns void.

But you could do this:

```
SomeMethod(new List<string>(new[] { "This compiles fine" }));
```

or use the collection initializer syntax:

```
SomeMethod(new List<string> { "This compiles fine" });
```

and if you wanted multiple elements:

```
SomeMethod(new List<string> { "elem1", "elem2", "elem3" });
```

Answer (score 2):

You see this error because Add method doesn't return anything. You can change this line to:

```
SomeMethod(new List<string>(){"This won't give compilation Error"});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new List<string>().Add("This give compilation Error")
```

returns void but the method `SomeMethod` expects a `List<string>`

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>.Add(T someItem)` does not return a reference to the list as a result of the operation, it returns void

Answer (score 1):

`List.Add` returns `void` and that's what you're passing into `SomeMethod`. Obviously that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Because Add method return type is Void and your expecting it to return collection.Check the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx
public void Add(
    T item
)

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeMethod(new List<string>() {"This give compilation Error"});
```

Comment: I am not sure this reason this was given a negative vote, this answer is perfectly valid, and is exactly what Dewasish suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your first option, you are passing the return of the `Add()` method to `SomeMethod()`, not the actual `List<string>` object.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the Add() method of generic List doesn't return an int, it's void.